# How to put new flags in my custom kernel version

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm working on Kernel Linux 2.6.32 and I'm modifying "open" system call.

Standard behavior works, but to try my code I've to use a new flag and I putted it in /asm-generic/fcntl.h.

The problem is that, when OS runs on my custom kernel, this flag is not known, and I've to put manually his value.

Are there other files inside kernel to define new flags?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its better you define your flag in Kconfig file.There many Kconfig files in kernel source code,you  can define it there and you can use it with  more flexibility.